# How can I interpret this error? Required type: Supplier<R, Provided: Collector<Object, capture of ?, java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>

Tags: java, list, generics, java-stream

I started using Java's stream a few weeks ago. I ran the code below and faced an error message.

1. How can I interpret this error? (More Specifically, what are "Supplier" and "capture" in the message?).
2. What is the best way to fix this error?

#### Source Code

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

#### Error Message

Required type: Supplier<R,
Provided: Collector<Object, capture of ?, java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) A, T exist so that Collector<T, A, List> conforms to Supplier

Comment: The error message you got refers to java's type system. As stated in the answer below, the compiler expects you to pass a `Supplier<R>` into the method. You passed `Collector<T, A, List>`, and compiler simply states that there are no possible values of `R`, `T` and `A` such that `Collector<T, A, List>` becomes assignable to `Supplier<R>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collectors.toList()` is a `Collector`. However, the `collect()` method of `IntStream`, which you are calling, expects 3 arguments - a `Supplier<R>`, an `ObjIntConsumer<R>` and a `BiConsumer<R, R>`.

If you want to pass `Collectors.toList()` to `collect()`, you should convert your `IntStream` to a `Stream<Integer>` first, since `Stream` has a `collect()` method that accepts a `Collector`.

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```